# Exit $('input[name^="myname"]').each( function() {

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, input, checkbox

I need to exit the javascript but am getting something odd.

There is an array of inputs that this uses.

When the "if" statement is true and "return true" or "return false" is to run, the alert('something') runs and I see the pop-up.

The script continues to execute.

I don't know if it stills executes the "..each" loop. Do you?

This needs to exit the .each loop and script entirely.

If no checkbox is false, then run the alert code outside the ...each(function()...

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="test[]" onclick="myfunction('a');" />
<input type="checkbox" id="b" name="test[]" onclick="myfunction('b');" />
<input type="checkbox" id="c" name="test[]" onclick="myfunction('c');" />
```

and the script...

```
<script>
function myfunction(instuff) {
    $('input[name^="test"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')  == false) {
            //...run code...
            return true; //return false; acts the same.
        }
    })
    //...run other code...
    alert('something');
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can consider to use VanillaJS instead JQuery ?

Comment: Regardless whether `true` or `false` a `return` terminates a function right there so as soon as any of those checkboxes are unchecked it's done so you never get an `alert()`

Comment: @zer00ne But it only terminates the `$.each()` callback function, not `myfunction()`.

Comment: ⏩[Look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪ and add the jQuery to make a [mcve]

Comment: `)}`  is a typo? Console would've picked that up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return false` from the callback function will stop the `.each()` loop. But the rest of `myfunction()` will continue to run.

If you want to stop the rest of the function, you can set a variable that you check after the loop.

```js
function myfunction(instuff) {
  let stop = false;
  $('input[name^="test"]').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        stop = true;
        return false;
      }
    } // fixed the code typo
  )
  if (stop) {
    return;
  }
  //...run other code...
  alert('something');
}
```